# List all JIRA tasks that are not blocked by other tasks

Tags: jira, jql

Using JIRA 4.4.3,

I've created a filter that list all the tasks that:
- The current user is assigned to;
- are Open;
- are not blocked by any other task.

To make it clear: the task that are ready for a user to work on.

We've installed the Craftforge JQL Functions plugin, and I've come with the following JQL query:

```
assignee = currentUser()
AND status in (Open)
AND issue NOT IN linkedIssuesFromFilter("All Issues", "Blocks", "Outward")
```

The problem is that when an issue that was blocking another issue is resolved, the "Blocks" link still exist -- and I don't want to delete it. But my query doesn't check if the linked issue is closed/resolved or not.

How can I add a condition "inside the IN statement" that will only return queries that are blocking the current task AND that are still OPEN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this clause from http://www.j-tricks.com/jqlt-links-functions.html:

```
issue not in linkedIssuesInQuery("status = Open", "is blocked by")
```

Comment: Error: `Unable to find JQL function 'linkedIssuesInQuery(status = Open, is blocked by)'.` Requires a plugin.

Comment: What plugin does this require? ScriptRunner?

Comment: @jasonhudgins Yes, that requires ScriptRunner.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [ScriptRunner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview), you can [use it](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/276130/how-to-return-unblocked-issues-in-an-issue-filter) to do this:

```
resolution = unresolved AND assignee = currentUser() AND (issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("resolution is not empty", blocks) OR issueFunction not in hasLinks("is blocked by"))
```

Answer (score -6):

I've created a new filter named "All active issues" that list all issues that are open, in progress or re-openned.

And I've used that new filter in my query instead of "All Issues".

Seems solved :)

Comment: @drozzy: If you have a better answer, feel free to post it and I will change the best answer flag if appropriate. For me this workaround appeared to have worked well so far... :)

Comment: That's great that you found a workaround to your problem; however those coming to this page from a search engine are likely to be looking for an answer to the original question. This answer doesn't help people "list all JIRA tasks that are not blocked by other tasks." Perhaps you should consider updating the question or moving your answer to a new, more relevant question.