# JQL get all not blocked tasks using tools available on the cloud version

Tags: cloud, jql

I'd like to get all the tasks that are not blocked by unresolved tasks. [List all JIRA tasks that are not blocked by other tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162667/list-all-jira-tasks-that-are-not-blocked-by-other-tasks) addresses this issue using addons that are not available on the cloud version of Jira. Is such a thing possible on the cloud version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in cloud version.

You can check, by JQL, the single issue using the syntax

```
issue in linkedIssues ("TEST-2","is blocked by")
```

Where TEST is a Project and "2" is ID of issue.

Comment: Ok that's what I feared. Thanks for the confirmation. It's absolutely crazy that such a key query is not possible.